# Bash directory comparison

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that takes two parameters, a source directory and an output directory. As it goes right now I use a simple

```
[ $1 == $2 ]
```

to check for duplicate directories which works just fine for well defined arguments. However, depending on where the bash file exists and what the user enters for args it may not always work and will cause a lot of problems. For example if the file resides in `/opt/script/` directory than a user can enter

```
./processLogs.sh ./ /opt/script/
```

and get past the simple check even though they point to the same directory. As you may know there are plenty of ways to navigate & point to a directory using different syntax but is there a way to ensure or check if they point to the same instance?

Comment: FYI, quotes are needed for this to work with directories whose names contain spaces or wildcards: `[ "$1" = "$2" ]`. You can also use the bash/ksh/zsh extension `[[ ]]`, as in: `[[ $1 = $2 ]]`. Note that the POSIX-standardized operator is `=`, **not** `==` -- shells that support `==` are going above and beyond the standard, and you shouldn't assume that every shell your code is ever run against will do so if your shebang is `#!/bin/sh` (which is guaranteed to be POSIX sh, but nothing more).

Comment: Err. `[[ $1 = "$2" ]]`, rather -- `[[ $1 = $2 ]]` treats `$2`'s contents as a shell pattern rather than a literal string.

Answer (score 2):

You can try applying `readlink -f` to the arguments:

```
if [[ $(readlink -f "$1") == $(readlink -f "$2") ]] ; then
    echo The arguments are the same. >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

`readlink` converts a path to its canonical representation and resolves links.

Comment: Note that `readlink -f` is a GNUism, and not available on all platforms. Otherwise, LGTM.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `realpath`:

```
[ "$(realpath "$1")" = "$(realpath "$2")" ]
```

`realpath` prints the resolved path, so it will work for things like `./` as well. It's good practice to wrap your variables in double quotes, to avoid problems with variables containing spaces.

Note that when using `[[ ]]`, [`==` is just a synonym for `=`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29).

Comment: Thanks Tom, I didn't know about using realpath. I'm very new to bash scripting and all my scripts have been fairly simple and small which is probably why I haven't had issues with [ x == y ] but very good to know.

Comment: @user3277223 actually what I said before wasn't quite right. It's fine to use `==` withing single `[ ]`, it's just a synonym. If you're using bash, you can also use `[[ ]]` as in choroba's answer, which is a more versatile (but slightly less portable) test.

Comment: @TomFenech, I actually would say it's _not_ fine, as POSIX doesn't specify `==`, so scripts doing so are less portable than those that don't. (That said, `realpath` isn't POSIX-standardized either, so maybe this is just a Linux-only answer in general).

Comment: On a different note, this answer needs more quotes to be entirely safe: `[ "$(realpath "$1")" = "$(realpath "$2")" ]`

Comment: `[ ... == ... ]` should never be used. It combines the unportability of `[[ ... == ... ]]` with the limitations of `[ ... = ... ]` (having to quote everything, no pattern matching, no proper boolean operators, etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the insight. Please feel free to edit my answer if you have the inclination.

Comment: @chepner that's a good point. As I said to Charles, any modifications are welcome (currently on my mobile...) Otherwise I'll add to my answer later. Thanks

Comment: Quoting improved, and link repointed to Freenode #bash channel wiki (maintained with more of an eye for best practices than the ABS).